# How to consume a winrt/c++ lib in WinUI3 Application

Tags: winui-3, c++-winrt

I am trying to consuming a winrt/C++ library (xxx.dll, xxx.winmd) in my application created by VS2022.

1. If I create UWP/C# application, it's easy to add the reference by:"right click project" -> Add -> reference -> Browse -> "then choose the winmd file" Then it works well.
2. But if I create WinUI3/C# application, there is no such option to add such reference.
   [image]

Since I must use WinUI3 App, so Could you please help on how to consume a winrt/c++ lib in WinUI3 Application?

Comment: You can use [CsWinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/create-winrt-component-winui-cswinrt), it provides packaged WinRT projection support for the C# language.